# how to install bugzilla-4.4.4 in xampp on windows 7

Tags: php, xampp, bugzilla

i downloaded the bugzilla-4.4.4 and put it on the xampp htdocs folder but it can't work,it show the below error.
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.

Error message:
couldn't create child process: 720002: index.cgi

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 500
localhost
22-Jul-14 9:57:16 AM
Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.17 OpenSSL/0.9.8o PHP/5.3.4 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

how can i use bugzila with xampp.

Answer (score 1):

You need to let apache execute .cgi scripts. Additionally, your .cgi script should be executable ('sudo chmod +x your_cgi_script.cgi').

Here is Apache's doc page on enabling cgi (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/cgi.html)